# Load more button pagination with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, pagination, infinite-scroll

I have found the package `mongoose-paginate`, so now I can control the number of items sent to the client.

But how do I make a 'load more' button that tells the server that it should send more items to the client AND insert the new items in the client without loading the page again?

Do I have to use `socket.io` to communicate between server and client?

Comment: I'd use React.js as it best handles the process of rendering new items. So on the initial load you render the React.js code and after that it takes care to make further request for pagination and update the DOM with the new data. You can use socket.io for client-server communication or library such as "reqwest".

Comment: [This tutorial](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-paginated-list/) shows how it works in the client-side with ReactJs.